# Find equation for a parabolic line that goes through two points in 3D space

Tags: geometry, 3d

I'm currently working on some computer graphics program where I want to show a line that "bounces" from point $A$ to point $B$, so I need an equation through which I can plug in values and interpolate the points that would trace the bounce.

Given two points, $A$ and $B$, in three dimensions, how do I determine the equation of a parabola that goes through $A$ and $B$?

Some additional information that might be helpful:

- Assume that a point $C$ is the midpoint between $A$ and $B$
- Assume that a point $D$ is the vertex of the parabolic line
- The length of line segment $\overline{CD}$ is a known variable/value

[image]

Comment: Is a parametric form good?

Comment: @mvw Yes, please! If anything it would be a good start I can work with. Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking about deriving an equation $f(x,y,z) = c$, which I would derive by applying some affine transformations to a standard parabola. But it would be a bit longer. Not sure if the effort would help with your implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first specify the line from $A$ to $B$:
$$
u(\lambda) = (1-\lambda) A + \lambda B
$$
where $\lambda \in [0, 1]$.

Now we stack the parabola on top:
$$
f(\lambda) = (\lambda - 0)(\lambda - 1) h
$$
where $h$ is such that $f(1/2) = \vec{CD}$, which is the vector from $C$ to $D$:
$$
f(1/2) = (1/2)(1/2 - 1) h = \vec{CD} \iff \\
h = -4 \cdot \vec{CD} \iff \\
f(\lambda) = 4 \, \vec{CD} \, \lambda(1 - \lambda) 
$$
This gives
$$
v(\lambda) = (1-\lambda) A + \lambda B  + 4\, \vec{CD} \, \lambda(1-\lambda)
$$
This requires $C = (A+B)/2$. That way $A$ and $B$ can be arbitrary points, they need not lie in the $z=0$ plane.

Comment: I've tested all answers I've received as of this writing, and they all work! And I'm choosing this answer as it's the first I received, and also the easiest for me to understand. One thing I would like to suggest is if you can reformat your answer to show $CD$ as $\vec{CD}$ instead. I think that would be clearer as I had a bit of a confusion when I was translating the parametric form into code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the quadratic Bezier curve whose three control points are $A$, $B$, and $E = 2D - C$. The first two are obvious. The third one, $E$, is a point that's vertically above $C$, at a height that's double the height of $D$.

The parametric equation of the curve is
$$
P(t) = (1-t)^2A + 2t(1-t)E + t^2B
$$
It's easy to confirm that $P(0)=A$, $P(1)=B$, and
\begin{aligned}
P(\tfrac12) &= \tfrac14A + \tfrac12E + \tfrac14B \\
&= \tfrac12(\tfrac12A + \tfrac12B) + \tfrac12(2D-C) \\
&= \tfrac12C + D - \tfrac12C \\
&= D
\end{aligned}

Or, if there's no good reason to use the Bezier form of the curve, you can express it in an even simpler manner by using quadratic [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). The equation is
$$
P(t) = (1-3t+2t^2)A + (4t - 4t^2)D + (2t^2-t)B
$$
Again, it's easy to confirm that $P(0)=A$, $P(\tfrac12) = D$, and $P(1)=B$.

Comment: This is really handy! One thing I'm struggling with, however, is trying to figure out how you arrived at that form of the Lagrange polynomial interpolation. Can you please expound on that? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it’s very useful. This is standard stuff in numerical analysis. To get my quadratic polynomials, you plug $t=0$, $t=\tfrac12$, $t=1$ into the standard formulas on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: In other words, plug $x_0=0$, $x_1 = \tfrac12$, $x_2=1$ into the formulas on this page: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/quadratic-lagrange-interpolating-polynomials

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with some linear algebra, you could use the basis vectors $C-A$ and $(0,0,d)$, where $d=||D-C||$ (the vertical distance between $D$ and $C$) to form a vector space in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in which your parabola lies. In this vector space, the parabola would just be $y=1-x^2$, or $\vec{c}(t)=(t,1-t^2)$. Then all we need is the change of basis matrix from our vector space to $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is pretty easy because its columns are the basis vectors:
$\begin{pmatrix}
| & 0 \\
C-A & 0 \\
| & d
\end{pmatrix}$.

If we let $A=(a_0,a_1,a_2)$ and $C=(c_0,c_1,c_2)$, this means our matrix is
$\begin{pmatrix}
c_0-a_0 & 0 \\
c_1-a_1 & 0 \\
c_2-a_2 & d
\end{pmatrix}$.
We can multiply our parabola by this matrix and shift by $C$ (because in our original $\vec{c}(t)$, the origin is in the place of $C$) to get an equation for the parabola in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$\begin{align}\vec{c}(t)=C+
\begin{pmatrix}
c_0-a_0 & 0 \\
c_1-a_1 & 0 \\
c_2-a_2 & d
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
t \\
1-t^2
\end{pmatrix}&=C+
\begin{pmatrix}
(c_0-a_0)t \\
(c_1-a_1)t \\
(c_2-a_2)t+d(1-t^2)
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=C+(C-A)t+(D-C)(1-t^2)
\end{align}$

Here's a geogebra file demonstration: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/rmfxuuft